# Cubic projective curves without rational points

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

I'm trying to study Elliptic Curves currently, and in the book I'm reading there seems to be one question they keep gravitating around but never actually even attempt to answer, even though it seems like an obvious question within the context.

Does there exist a cubic protective curve that has no rational points but has points over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for every prime $p$?

I suspect this is an ill-formed question that stems from a misunderstanding of the subject, so if this question doesn't really make sense can you help me understand where it is wrong, and if not, is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: This paper seems to be relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910124.pdf

There, they construct a 1-dimensional family of genus 1 curves with no rational points, but with $\mathbb{Q}_p$ points for every $p$. In fact, for all but finitely many $p$, the $\mathbb{Q}_p$ points actually come from $\mathbb{F}_p$ points.

Comment: There is a very famous example by Cassels, namely the smooth projective cubic $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3$ has a $\mathbb Q_p$-rational point for all $p$ (and hence a $\mathbb Z_p$-rational point since it is homogeneous and hence an $\mathbb F_p$-rational point for all $p$), but has no rational points.